# Dispatching store actions from API methods that are imported in Sagas causes dependency cycles

Tags: redux, redux-saga

I have a React application with API methods based on socket.io.
File `webSocket.js` handles Socket connection, as well as basic methods like sending and getting the data, which are used across all of my app.

I have several Redux store properties that I have to change during various socket events. For that I imported my Redux store from `store.js` into `webSocket.js` and use `store.dispatch()` to trigger corresponding actions.

This solution worked fine, until I started to implement `redux-saga` in my project.
In my basic saga, I need to call an API method, which relies on a `send` method from `webSocket.js`. Since the saga is imported in the `store.js` to connect it via `redux-saga` middleware, and the `store.js` is imported in `webSocket.js`, I get a Linter error for `Dependency cycle`, even though I only import specific methods.

It's not like it's breaking my app, but I would like to avoid such loopholes for peace of mind.
I couldn't find any leads to my case in Redux or Redux-Saga docs.
I'm kinda new to Redux, so maybe I'm missing some basic stuff?
If so, what would be a right solution for my scenario?

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to break up the websocket functions into two files - one for sending websocket messages and one for handling incoming messages. The message sending file should not rely on the store as it should have no need to dispatch actions and the sagas can then import from that file without a dependency cycle. The income message handling file will dispatch events through the store and not rely on the sagas. Depending on how you set up your socket you made need a third file for connection management that the sender and handler files depend on.

In general you're looking to find the separation of concerns that breaks the dependency cycle, and I believe separating message sending and handling would be a good place to create that separation.

Comment: Yes, that seems like a reasonable solution. Thanks, I'll look into it!